# How to extract the value of a key stored in one column from a JSON object stored in another column using Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

A table with a column `C1` containing a `JSON` object and a column `C2` containing key. I want to extract the value of the key from the json object.

data preview:

[image]

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(C1, C2)
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(C1, CONCAT('$.',C2))
FROM MY_TABLE:
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(C1, CAST(CONCAT('$.',C2) AS STRING))
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(C1, (SELECT CONCAT('$.', C2) FROM MY_TABLE))
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Error thrown: JSONPath has to be a string or a query parameter

Comment: Please share more info about your data.
Is the json value containing just single value? what is the key format?

Comment: @AsiSalo  Added the data preview above.